# Filter one table after another one - Angular 2++

Tags: angular, datatables, angular2-template

i'm in the process of learning Angular 2++ and i want to create 2 dynamic tables that can be filtered when clicking on the row of another. For eg. let's say we have the next tables:

---

Table 1

```
ID1     Box Name   Size
```

```
1       BOX1       17sqm
2       BOX2       18sqm
3       BOX3       19sqm
```

---

Table 2

```
ID1     ID2     Box assets    Pieces
```

```
1       a       Chair         3pcs
1       b       Table         2pcs
2       c       TVs           4pcs
2       d       Lawnmower     2pcs
3       e       Vehicle       1pcs
```

---

So when i click the 1st row of 1st table it will show me just the 2 rows of second table. If i click the last row of the second table, it will show me just the last row of 1st table.

Is this possible?

Comment: Ofcourse this is possible. What problem are you facing developing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain 2 array of objects to display 2 tables. We need to have a unique id in table 1, which will be foriegn key (association key) in Table 2

From the above table, 'ID1' is the unique id in table 1 and 'ID1' is the assocation key in Table2. When we click item in table 1, use the ID1 value and apply filter to Table 2 and display the result in DOM.